# Como posso combinar um checkbox com um switch?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Estou tentando fazer uma validação na resposta marcada em um formulário. A intenção é criar uma questão de múltipla escolha onde se o item marcado for o correto ele apresente uma resposta, se não, que apresente outra mensagem. A resposta certa aparece para mim, mas a errada não. O que pode estar errado? Obrigado!

Javascript

```
resp_a = document.getElementById("01_a").checked = false;
resp_b = document.getElementById("01_b").checked = false;
resp_c = document.getElementById("01_c").checked = true;
resp_d = document.getElementById("01_d").checked = false;
resp_e = document.getElementById("01_e").checked = false;   

switch(){
    case resp_a:
        document.getElementById("resp_01").innerHTML = "Você errou, tente novamente!";
        break;

    case resp_b:
        document.getElementById("resp_01").innerHTML = "Você errou, tente novamente!";
        break;

    case resp_c:
        document.getElementById("resp_01").innerHTML = "Você acertou!";
        break;

    case resp_d:
        document.getElementById("resp_01").innerHTML = "Você errou, tente novamente!";
        break;

    case resp_e:
        document.getElementById("resp_01").innerHTML = "Você errou, tente novamente!";
        break;
}
```

Comment: Switch não servirá para isso pois você tem que verificar todas as resposta, ao encontrar a primeira resposta correta o switch será finalizado.

Answer (score 1):

Este código que você postou está meio vazio, falta saber as opções corretas.

Mas você pode fazer isso para validar os checkbox marcados e validar de acordo com a resposta correta.

```js
function verificaRespostas () {
            event.preventDefault()
            var myForm = document.querySelector('[data-js=myForm]');
            var resposta ='';
            for(var i=0;i <= myForm.children.length; i++){
                if(myForm.children[i].type =='checkbox'){
                    if(myForm.children[i].checked){
                        resposta += myForm.children[i].value +' está correta <br />'
                    }else{
                        resposta += myForm.children[i].value +' está errada <br />'
                    }                    
                }
                document.getElementById('respostas').innerHTML = resposta;                
            }
        }
```

```css
.form {
        width: 500;
        padding: 10px;
        border: solid 1px #EEE;
    }
    .btn{
        background-color: #FFF;
        padding: 20px;
        border: solid 1px #EEE;
        font-weight: bold;      
    }
    .btn:hover{
        background-color: #DDD;
    }
```

```html
<div id="respostas" class="resposta">
<form class="form" data-js="myForm" name="myForm">
        Resposta A
        <input id="resp_a" name="resp_a" type="checkbox" value="Resposta A">      
        
        Resposta B
        <input id="resp_b" name="resp_b" type="checkbox" value="Resposta B">        
        
        Resposta C
        <input id="resp_c" name="resp_c" type="checkbox" value="Resposta C">        
        
        Resposta D
        <input id="resp_d" name="resp_d" type="checkbox" value="Resposta D">        
        
        Resposta E
        <input id="resp_e" name="resp_e" type="checkbox" value="Resposta E">        
        
        <input type="submit" class="btn" onclick="verificaRespostas()" value="Verificar respostas" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tens de colocar um argumento no `switch` ele não pode estar simplesmente vazio. Tens de ter `switch (uma_variável){` e depois caso seja `x` fazer algo, caso seja `y` fazer algo, etc...

Dito isso acho que o `switch` não é o mais indicado aqui. Podias fazer isso assim:

```js
function analizarPergunta(nome, respostaCerta) {
    var escolhida = document.querySelector('[name="' + nome + '"]:checked');
    return respostaCerta === escolhida.value;
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var acertou = analizarPergunta('pergunta_01', '01_c')
    alert(acertou ? 'Correto!' : 'Errado!');
});
```

```html
A: <input type="radio" name="pergunta_01" value="01_a"> 
B: <input type="radio" name="pergunta_01" value="01_b">
C: <input type="radio" name="pergunta_01" value="01_c">
D: <input type="radio" name="pergunta_01" value="01_d">
E: <input type="radio" name="pergunta_01" value="01_e">

<p><button>Verificar</button></p>
<p id="resp_01"></p>
```